# Oracle RAC installation failure: disk share issue

Tags: linux, storage, oracle, shared-storage

Oracle RAC installation is failing because of shared disk issue. While running "runcluvfy.sh" to verify the disk share between nodes. it is failing on node2.

I have collected trace logs of following commands for analysis.

`./runcluvfy.sh comp ssa -n rac-node1 -s /dev/mapper/asm-data1p1`

Output - https://pastebin.com/SfCj88W4

`./runcluvfy.sh comp ssa -n rac-node2 -s /dev/mapper/asm-data1p1`

Output - https://pastebin.com/Y7eUzhTF

Also I compared the multipath output and disk attributes and found identical on both nodes.

## **NODE-1**

**multipath o/p for asm-data1 disk on node-1**

``` asm-data1 (3600507638081029b4400000000000000) dm-2 IBM,2145
size=800G features='1 queue_if_no_path' hwhandler='0' wp=rw
``-+- policy='round-robin 0' prio=30 status=active
  |- 3:0:0:0  sdb 8:16  active ready running
 ``- 4:0:0:0  sdm 8:192 active ready running ```

**WWID of disks**

`[root@rac-node1 ~]# scsi_id -g -u -d /dev/sdb
3600507638081029b4400000000000000
[root@rac-node1 ~]# scsi_id -g -u -d /dev/sdm
3600507638081029b4400000000000000`

**Disk identifiers of disks**

`[root@rac-node1 ~]# /sbin/scsi_id -p 0x80 -g -u /dev/sdb
SIBM_2145_00e02040a6d1XX00
[root@rac-node1 ~]# /sbin/scsi_id -p 0x80 -g -u /dev/sdm
SIBM_2145_00e02040a6d1XX00`

## **NODE-2**

**multipath o/p for asm-data1 disk on node-2**

``` asm-data1 (3600507638081029b4400000000000000) dm-2 IBM,2145
size=800G features='1 queue_if_no_path' hwhandler='0' wp=rw
``-+- policy='round-robin 0' prio=30 status=active
  |- 3:0:0:0  sdb 8:16  active ready running
  ``- 4:0:0:0  sdm 8:192 active ready running ```

**WWID of disks**

`[root@rac-node2 ~]# scsi_id -g -u -d /dev/sdb
3600507638081029b4400000000000000
[root@rac-node2 ~]# scsi_id -g -u -d /dev/sdm
3600507638081029b4400000000000000`

**Disk identifiers of disks**

`[root@rac-node2 ~]#  /sbin/scsi_id -p 0x80 -g -u /dev/sdb
SIBM_2145_00e02040a6d1XX00
[root@rac-node2 ~]#  /sbin/scsi_id -p 0x80 -g -u /dev/sdm
SIBM_2145_00e02040a6d1XX00`

## **Additional Information collected form trace log**

**Node1 Output**

`# /tmp/CVU_11.2.0.4.0_grid/exectask.sh -getstinfo -getdiskinfo /dev/mapper/asm-data1%/dev/mapper/asm-data1p1
<CV_VAL>
    <disk>
        <disk_name>/dev/mapper/asm-data1</disk_name>
        <disk_signature>00e02040a6d1XX00|</disk_signature>
        <NUMPARTS>0</NUMPARTS>
        <disk_state>0</disk_state>
        <disk_size>858991362048</disk_size>
        <disk_owner>grid</disk_owner>
        <disk_group>asmadmin</disk_group>
        <disk_permissions>0660</disk_permissions>
    </disk>
</CV_VAL>
<CV_VRES>0</CV_VRES>
<CV_LOG>Exectask:getDiskInfo success</CV_LOG>
<CV_ERES>0</CV_ERES>`

**Node2 Output**

`# /tmp/CVU_11.2.0.4.0_grid/exectask.sh -getstinfo -getdiskinfo /dev/mapper/asm-data1%/dev/mapper/asm-data1p1
<CV_ERR>location:sprvsdsk opname:findDisk category:10011</CV_ERR>
<CV_VRES>10011</CV_VRES>
<CV_LOG>Exectask:getDiskInfo failed</CV_LOG>
<CV_ERES>0</CV_ERES>`

**General Information**

`[root@rac-node2 ~]# cat /etc/oracle-release
Oracle Linux Server release 6.10
[root@rac-node2 ~]# rpm -qa | grep multi
device-mapper-multipath-libs-0.4.9-106.0.1.el6_10.1.x86_64
device-mapper-multipath-0.4.9-106.0.1.el6_10.1.x86_64`

Comment: Talk to us about what your shared disk actually is, how it's connected etc.

Comment: shared disk is from SAN connected via Fiber HBA.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use external site to show your errors and post only the relevant one, `TaskSharedStorageAccess:Shared Storage Accessibility:/dev/mapper/asm-data1p1:TASK_SUMMARY:FAILED:CRITICAL:OPERATION_FAILED`, I don't see the sense to partition a lun, to solve your problem in the second node `partprobe /dev/mapper/asm-data1`

Comment: Ran partprobe command and tried again. Same error.

Comment: @ArunS ls -l /dev/mapper/asm-data1p1 ?

Comment: `[root@rac-node2 ~]#  ls -l /dev/mapper/asm-data1p1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 8 Oct 24 23:15 /dev/mapper/asm-data1p1 -> ../dm-13`

`[root@rac-node2 ~]# ls -l /dev/dm-13
brw-rw---- 1 grid asmadmin 249, 13 Oct 24 23:15 /dev/dm-13`

Comment: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1202013